# Insert List<object> into Elasticsearch with NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I have a lot of different collections of values I generate at runtime and want to send them to ElasticSearch. I can represent them as `List<object>` or if really doesn't work any other way, as `List<string>`. But I can't find any example how to do that. Here is an example of the code which doesn't work. There is probably a lot wrong with it, so any additional pointers are highly appreciated.

```
  var client = new ElasticClient(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
            client.CreateIndex("testentry");
            var values = new List<object> {"StringValue", 123, DateTime.Now};
            var indexResponse = client.Index(values, descriptor => descriptor.Index("testentry"));
            Console.WriteLine(indexResponse.DebugInformation);
```

Which results in:

```
Invalid NEST response built from a unsuccessful low level call on POST: /testentry/list%601
# Audit trail of this API call:
 - [1] BadResponse: Node: http://localhost:9200/ Took: 00:00:00.0600035
# ServerError: ServerError: 400Type: mapper_parsing_exception Reason: "failed to parse" CausedBy: "Type: not_x_content_exception Reason: "Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes""
```

and

```
[2016-09-17 14:16:20,955][DEBUG][action.index             ] [Gin Genie] failed to execute [index {[t
estentry][list`1][AVc4E3HaPglqpoLcosDo], source[_na_]}] on [[testentry][1]]
MapperParsingException[failed to parse]; nested: NotXContentException[Compressor detection can only
be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes];
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentParser.parseDocument(DocumentParser.java:156)
```

I'm using Elasticsearch.Net 2.4.3 and NEST 2.4.3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[In addition to Henrik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39547785/1831), you could also index values in a `Dictionary<string, object>`

```
public class MyType
{
    public MyType()
    {
        Values = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }

    public Dictionary<string, object> Values { get; private set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    var myType = new MyType
    {
        Values =
        {
            { "value1", "StringValue" },
            { "value2", 123 },
            { "value3", DateTime.Now },
        }
    };

    client.Index(myType, i => i.Index("index-name"));
}
```

The `Dictionary<string,object>` will be serialized to a json object with property names to match the dictionary keys

```
{
  "values": {
    "value1": "StringValue",
    "value2": 123,
    "value3": "2016-09-18T18:41:48.7344837+10:00"
  }
}
```

Within Elasticsearch, the mapping will be inferred as an [object type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html).

Answer (score 3):

[Arrays](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/array.html) with a mixture of datatypes are not supported.

You could convert all of the values to strings:

```
client.CreateIndex("testentry");
var values = new List<string> { "StringValue", "123", DateTime.Now.ToString() };
var indexResponse = client.Index(new { Values = values}, descriptor => descriptor.Index("testentry").Type("test"));
```

Or specify the fields that the values should be indexed to:

```
client.CreateIndex("testentry");
var values = new { Field1 = "StringValue", Field2 = 123, Field3 = DateTime.Now };
var indexResponse = client.Index(values, descriptor => descriptor.Index("testentry").Type("test"));
```

Consider specifying the type of the document with the IndexDescriptor or create a class for the document.